# SELECT INTO with regexp_replace() doesn't write changes into newly generated table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, ddl, regular-expression

I have been using this query in Postgres 9.1 in order to remove `''` from existing data.
Below is a sample of the data before running `regexp_replace()`:

```
6''
6''
6''
20''
12''
18''
20''
8''
10''
''
''
```

Upon running:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(regexp_replace, $$^'*$$, '' , 'g')
from temp_4 order by id;
```

I receive this clean output:

```
6
6
6
20
12
18
20
8
10
( ) <- stand-in for " "
( )
```

however when attempt to then write these results into a table, say using:

```
select * into table_3 from (select REGEXP_REPLACE(tbl, $$^"''*,*$$, '' , 'g') from temp_2 order by id) as temp_3;
```

I receive

```
6
6
6
20
12
18
20
8
10
''
''
```

Where `''` has been removed from all values, except in the case it was the only value present. I have attempted to whitelist using `[\w\s*]` all other values instead of blacklist with this regex `^'*`, but in both instances values of `''`. I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.

How do I write my table where I can replace `''` with `0` or null values?

Also, is my syntax terribly wrong in my attempts to write this data to other tables? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `SELECT regexp_replace($$6''$$, $$^'*$$, '' , 'g');` returns `6''`.  Could you please post a set of consistent examples?  Also, remove the double quotes if they are not part of the real data.

Comment: I have edited the data to more appropriately fit. What do you mean by more consistent examples? Also Yes my issue is that select regexp_replace($$6''$$, $$^'*$$, '','g'); returns 6'', when I specifically dilineate '' with the regex of ^'*. I had tested my regex with http://regexpal.com/ in order to ensure that my string was correctly matchin, hence my confusion as to why 6'' is cleaned appropriately but '' by itself is not recognized.

Comment: In other words, your `regexp_replace()` removes quotes from the start of a line, so at least one of the example data, query and output does not match the others.

Answer (score 2):

Your `regexp_replace()` statement is invalid. It would work like this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(tbl, '('''')$', '' , 'g')
FROM (
 VALUES
  ('6''''')
 ,('6''''')
 ,('6''''')
 ,('20''''')
 ,('12''''')
 ,('18''''')
 ,('20''''')
 ,('8''''')
 ,('10''''')
 ,('''''')
 ,('''''')
) tbl(tbl)
```

Your `SELECT INTO` statement is invalid. It would look like this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(tbl, '('''')$', '' , 'g')
INTO   temp table_4
FROM   temp_2
ORDER  BY id;
```

But I would use **neither**.

`SELECT INTO` is discouraged. Only supported for historical reasons. Use [**`CREATE TABLE AS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html) instead, which is the SQL standard way. [Per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html)

> `CREATE TABLE AS` is functionally similar to `SELECT INTO`. **`CREATE TABLE
>   AS` is the recommended syntax**, since this form of `SELECT INTO` is not
>   available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the `INTO` clause
>   differently. Furthermore, `CREATE TABLE AS` offers a superset of the
>   functionality provided by `SELECT INTO`.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

For the presented examples, [`rtrim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is much simpler and faster:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table_4 AS 
SELECT rtrim(tbl, '''')     -- trim all trailing '
FROM   temp_2
ORDER  BY id;
```

Comment: `select into .. from ..` to create a new table is **not** defined in the SQL standard. The `select into` syntax in the standard is only defined for to read a *single* row into one or more host *variables* (e.g. in PL/pgSQL). To create a new table based on a select, the SQL standard only defines `create table .. as ...`

Comment: Why not use dollar-quotation?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks, I had the reason backwards. Fixed.

Comment: @dezso: No particular reason. I tend to use the shortest form. In this case either form is equally long.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I always get confused by these multiplicated qutes so I always use dollar quoting in similar cases.  I simply find it more readable.

Comment: @dezso: I tend to agree. What tipped me towards escaping quotes was the use of `$` in the regexp, which would result in ambiguity with dollar quotes without a token. Also a bit confusing for newcomers.