# Is there a way to partially initialize a TYPE?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, syntax, cast, composite-types

I have created a custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type as(name text, street text, location text);
```

Initializing such a type is easy:

```
SELECT ROW('a', 'b', 'c')::my_type;
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way to initialize a type partially, meaning that all unmentioned columns are set to null implicitly. In pseudo-code, something like:

```
SELECT ROW('a', 'c')::my_type(name, location);
```

In addition, is there also a way to initialize a type when the columns are not mentioned in the correct order? In pseudo-code, something like:

```
SELECT ROW('c', 'a', 'b')::my_type(location, name, street);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code examples based on your type definition:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (name text, street text, location text);
```

Your syntax is not possible (as you already know). A [plain cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) does not allow a (partial) list of fields.

```
SELECT ROW('a', 'c')::my_type(name, location);
```

In a **plain SQL cast** expression, you have to provide NULL values (or some other default) for missing fields:

```
SELECT ROW('a', NULL, 'c')::my_type;
```

Or, using a row type literal as input:

```
SELECT '(a,NULL,c)'::my_type;
```

[**`INSERT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) or [**`UPDATE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) statements can target fields of composite types individually. (The underlying type is derived from the target.) Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (tbl_id serial, comp my_type);

INSERT INTO tbl (comp.name, comp.location) VALUES ('a', 'c')

UPDATE tbl
SET    comp.name = 'X'
     , comp.street = 'Y'
WHERE  tbl_id = 1;
```

Fields not filled explicitly default to NULL. (Unless the type has a different *default*, which would be uncommon.)

Not possible for [**`DELETE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html), obviously, which always removes the whole row. The logical equivalent would be to set a subfield `NULL`:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    comp.name = NULL
WHERE  tbl_id = 1;
```

Normally you would use variables in a procedural language function - default **PL/pgSQL**. There you have [**`SELECT INTO`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW). And you can address fields of a composite type individually. Demo:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    _var my_type;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _var.location, _var.name  -- in any chosen order
          'c', 'a';
   RAISE NOTICE '%', _var;
END
$$
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=810f380237f7f67008704ac96c7bfb31)*

Do not confuse PL/pgSQL assignment with `SELECT INTO` and the SQL command `SELECT INTO` (which should not be used at all, use `CREATE TABLE AS` instead). See:

- [SELECT INTO with regexp_replace() doesn't write changes into newly generated table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62012/select-into-regexp-replace-doesnt-write-changes-into-newly-generated-table/62204#62204)

Related, more sophisticated tricks:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)
- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711432/how-to-set-value-of-composite-variable-field-using-dynamic-sql)
  (demonstrating the hstore `#=` operator)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do this using any type

1. That's constructor takes a `record` and supports merge (or as PostgreSQL likes to say "concatenate" (`||`)). An example of this is `hstore`.
2. Using any type that supports an operation on a record, with a composite type. Two options that come to mind are `jsonb` and `hstore`.

## [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
-- In a single call to jsonb_populate_record
SELECT jsonb_populate_record(
  null::my_type,
  jsonb_build_object('name', 'Evan')
);

-- With a subsequent merge after construction
SELECT jsonb_populate_record(
  null::my_type,
  '{}'
) || jsonb_build_object('name', 'Evan');
```

## [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)

`hstore` actually supports doing this directly on a row,

```
-- With single-call methods to #= or populate_record
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
SELECT null::my_type #= hstore('name', 'Evan');
SELECT populate_record(null::my_type, hstore('name', 'Evan'))
```

Here is what the first option looks like.

```
-- With a subsequent merge after construction
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
SELECT hstore(null::my_type) || hstore('name', 'Evan');
```

## See Also

- [*Why doesn't jsonb constructor from a NULL record behave like hstore constructor?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/217721/2639)