# Why doesn't jsonb constructor from a NULL record behave like hstore constructor?

Tags: postgresql, json, null, hstore

When I construct an [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
SELECT hstore(null::my_type);
                     hstore                     
------------------------------------------------
 "name"=>NULL, "street"=>NULL, "location"=>NULL
(1 row)
```

While the [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) method,

```
SELECT to_jsonb(null::my_type);
 to_jsonb 
----------

(1 row)
```

This creates a surprising effect too when you try to merge (`||`) another like type,

```
SELECT hstore(null::my_type) || hstore('name', 'Evan');
                     ?column?                     
--------------------------------------------------
 "name"=>"Evan", "street"=>NULL, "location"=>NULL
(1 row)

SELECT to_jsonb(null::my_type) || jsonb_build_object('name', 'Evan');
 ?column? 
----------

(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround here is to construct the jsonb by proxy of `jsonb_populate_record`

```
SELECT jsonb_populate_record(
  null::my_type,
  '{}'
);
```

Or, in the event you're just trying to update the record type, you can do it directly with the one call.

```
SELECT jsonb_populate_record(
  null::my_type,
  jsonb_build_object('name', 'Evan')
);
```

Comment: `to_jsonb()` function declared as `STRICT` so it always returns `NULL` for `NULL` argument. `to_jsonb('(,,)'::my_type)` should to work as you expecting.